# Where to put <<EOF when looping using sshpass?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sshpass

I am using the following script to loop through all files in a local folder and upload them to an `sftp` location using `sshpass`. I have already tried the `put` statement to upload a single file. But I somehow have problem on where to put my `<<EOF` and `EOF` correctly? Or is it something else missing?

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES= /MY_LOCAL_FOLDER_PATH/*
sshpass -p 'MY_PASSWORD' sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss MY_USERNAME@FTP_URL:/Import 
<<EOF
for f in $FILES   
do
chmod +X $f
put $f
done
EOF
```

I put the `chmod` there because I got "permission denied" on my files.

Comment: I would rather recommend you using a Batch file than doing harakiri with IO redirection.

Comment: @Jakuje this is all in an `.sh` file. Would be glad to see your solution if you have any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate the `put` commands for `sftp` as input, you'll have to pipe them. You can't process loops within a here-document. Also, you shouldn't use `sshpass -p`, as the program's command line is visible to all processes on the system via `proc` and `ps`, even those of other users. (very briefly, but visible anyway.) Environment variables are only visible to the same user, though in general, ssh keys might still be preferable.

Something like this might work:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SSHPASS=MY_PASSWORD
for f in /path/* ; do 
    echo put "$f"
done | sshpass -e sftp user@whereever:/path
unset SSHPASS
```

Any commands inside the loop are executed locally, anything you want to pass to `sftp` as commands should be printed via `echo` or such.
(Of course, the commands shouldn't print anything that's not supposed to go to `sftp`.)

Comment: what does the line `export SSHPASS=xxx` do and what should I write for the "xxx" values?

Comment: @Disasterkid, `export var=value` assigns a value to the named variable and marks it exported so that it's visible in the environment of the commands started by the script

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `<<EOF` аt the end of the line after `sshpass`

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES= /MY_LOCAL_FOLDER_PATH/*
sshpass -p 'MY_PASSWORD' sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss MY_USERNAME@FTP_URL:/Import <<EOF
for f in $FILES   
do
chmod +X $f
put $f
done
EOF
```

Comment: `$f` needs to be backslash-escaped. (`$f` => `\$f`)

Comment: `sftp` doesn't support a `for` command, so you'll just get a number of `Invalid command.` errors